# Changing layer id in QGIS

Tags: qgis, pyqgis-3

I use `QgsLayerDefinition.loadLayerDefinition(path, project, rootGroup)` in my code. But this method changes ids of loaded layers. I need the codes to be old. Is there any way to change ids (for example any custom) of layers after loading layer definitions? Or have any other ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To solve my problem, it was enough for me to use the idea of methods `loadLayerDefinition`, using the minimum functionality of these methods (+I added some restriction).

```py
def loadLayerDefinitionCustom(self, path, project, rootGroup):
    file = QFile(path)
    doc = QtXml.QDomDocument()
    doc.setContent(file)

    context = QgsReadWriteContext()
    context.setPathResolver( QgsPathResolver(path))
    context.setProjectTranslator(project)
    return self.loadLayerDefinitionDocCustom( doc, project, rootGroup, context )


def loadLayerDefinitionDocCustom(self, doc, project, rootGroup, context):
    root = QgsLayerTreeGroup()

    # # check for id layers in project
    # map_layers = list(QgsProject.instance().mapLayers().keys())
    # treeLayerNodes = doc.elementsByTagName("maplayer")
    # for i in range(treeLayerNodes.count()):
    #     node = treeLayerNodes.at(i)
    #     idval = node.firstChildElement("id").text()
    #     if idval in map_layers:
    #         self.iface.messageBar().pushMessage(
    #                 u"Map already consists layer ID",
    #                 u"", 
    #                 duration=5,
    #                 level=2
    #             )
    #         raise Exception("Map already consists layer ID " + idval)

    layerTreeElem = doc.documentElement().firstChildElement( "layer-tree-group" )
    loadInLegend = True
    if layerTreeElem is not None:
        root.readChildrenFromXml( layerTreeElem, context )
        loadInLegend = False

    layers = QgsLayerDefinition.loadLayerDefinitionLayers( doc, context )
    project.addMapLayers(layers, loadInLegend)

    for layer in layers:
        layer.resolveReferences(project)
    root.resolveReferences(project)

    nodes = root.children()
    for idx, n in enumerate(nodes):
        root.takeChild(n)
    rootGroup.insertChildNodes(0, nodes)

    return True
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `QgsLayerDefinition.loadLayerDefinitionLayers`.

[Documentation](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsLayerDefinition.html#a2e2c459fa2a508283c335d5a82db08a0):

> ```
> QgsLayerDefinition::loadLayerDefinitionLayers(QDomDocument & document,
>                                               QgsReadWriteContext & context)
> ```
>
> Creates new layers from a layer definition document.
> This is a low-level routine that **does not resolve layer ID conflicts**,
> dependencies and joins

Therefore you should use `loadLayerDefinitionLayers` instead of `loadLayerDefinition` so that you don't need to change ids.

```
layer_list = QgsLayerDefinition().loadLayerDefinitionLayers(path)
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayers(layer_list)
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggested method. Indeed, this allows to load layers with their own identifiers, but joins are lost. Besides, it does not allow to preserve the structure (groups) and the order of the layers, in contrast to the `loadLayerDefinition`

Comment: So, I rewrote methods `loadLayerDefinition`, where I excluded part of the code with handling layers IDs.

Comment: Did you use Python or did you change source code (C++)? If Python, it will be nice you share your solution as an answer here.

Comment: Yes, I will share my Python code. But I doubt that anyone would need my solution. this is applicable for my specific task :)